# Pycharm IDE coding on remote server with ssh

Tags: python, ssh, ftp, pycharm

I wonder if there is any way to coding python with remote server data and run the python script on remote server with pycharm only installed on my local machine?

The remote server can be access by two ip address (ssh and ftp each), id and password.
But when I try to use pycharm professional project interpreter, there always an error like this  (the ip address I used is for ssh):

[image: Error1]

[image: Error2]

I know the easiest way is install `jupyter notebbok` on my remote server, but I don't have permission to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFTP error "Received message too long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250379/sftp-error-received-message-too-long)

Comment: My problem is I don't  have permission to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Comment: There's more than one answer on the other question.

Comment: Basically are the same, I don't have permission to change anything on yhe server.